# Smartedit loading issue in hybris 2211 with Spartacus 3.4

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

1. After updating hybris to 2211.3 version smartedit keeps on loading when clicking on homepage.
2. After doing multiple back button and selecting homepage again, site loads but Perspective Toolbar not seen.

We have tried to add webApplicationInjector.js in Spartacus 3.4 as suggested in https://microlearning.opensap.com/media/Connecting+SmartEdit+to+a+Spartacus+Storefront+-+SAP+Commerce+Cloud/1_f3oraeow but no  sucess

Also https://answers.sap.com/questions/13527176/upgrading-smartedit-from-67-to-2105-issues-on-load.html removed as suggested.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @MirosławGrochowski yes Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at O.b.<computed>.get (vendors.js:2:4223388)

Comment: @MirosławGrochowski After doing the steps in https://microlearning.opensap.com/media/Connecting+SmartEdit+to+a+Spartacus+Storefront+-+SAP+Commerce+Cloud/1_f3oraeow. Index.js i have modified inside the src folder now i can see new error Uncaught Error: https://localhost:9002 is not allowed to override this storefront.
    at VM284018 webApplicationInjector.js:2:5879.  This same error is i have seen in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/ telling to add allowOrgin. that is already in place in my application

Comment: @kritikanarang are you able to solve this?

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13853226/commerce-2211-smartedit-page-loading-issue-for-spa.html . Issue is with spa 3.4 . @sree not able to find solution. SAP suggested to move to spa 5

Comment: I have the very same problem with forever loading smartedit with 2211 and spartacus 6.0